# unset array element if length is less

Tags: php, arrays

I've following array:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [team1_id] => 2
            [agegroup_id] => 18
            [team2_id] => 3
            [team_ground] => Adeilade
            [matchdate] => 2016-04-01
            [matchtime] => 9:00 AM
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [team1_id] => 3
            [agegroup_id] => 18
            [team2_id] => 2
            [team_ground] => Adeilade
            [matchdate] => 2016-04-13
            [matchtime] => 10:00 AM
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [team1_id] => 2
            [agegroup_id] => 18
            [team2_id] => 3
            [team_ground] => Adeilade
            [matchdate] => 2016-04-20
            [matchtime] => 2:00 PM
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [team1_id] => 3
            [agegroup_id] => 18
            [team2_id] => 2
            [team_ground] => Adeilade
            [matchdate] => 04/07/2016
            [matchtime] => 5:00 PM
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [team1_id] => 9
            [agegroup_id] => 36
            [team2_id] => 4
            [team_ground] => Motera Stadium
            [matchdate] => 2016-04-13
            [matchtime] => 9:00 AM
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [team1_id] => 4
            [agegroup_id] => 36
            [team2_id] => 9
            [team_ground] => Motera Stadium
            [matchdate] => 2016-04-13
            [matchtime] => 5:00 PM
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [team1_id] => 1
            [agegroup_id] => 37
            [team2_id] => 8
            [team_ground] => Eden Garden
            [matchdate] => 2016-04-18
            [matchtime] => 7:00 PM
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [team1_id] => 8
            [agegroup_id] => 37
            [team2_id] => 1
            [team_ground] => Eden Garden
            [matchdate] => 2016-04-25
            [matchtime] => 8:00 PM
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [team1_id] => 1
            [agegroup_id] => 37
            [team2_id] => 8
            [team_ground] => Eden Garden
            [matchdate] => 04/26/2016
            [matchtime] => 8:00 PM
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [agegroup_id] => 18
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [agegroup_id] => 36
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [agegroup_id] => 37
        )

)
```

If array is having only one element then I've to unset it. In this case I want to unset array index `0,5,8` in PHP. How to unset the array index when it is having less elements?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but the key is not fixed. This is dynamic array

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use `array_filter` over here as

```
$result = array_filter($your_array,function($v){ return count($v) > 1;});
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a simple foreach:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
  {
     if(sizeOf($array[$key]) < 2)
         unset($array[$key]);
  }
```

**Here is a working [DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/lite?code=%3C?php%5Cn%20$array%20=%20array(%5Cn%20array%5Cn%20(%22team1_id%22%20=%3E%202,%22agegroup_id%22%20=%3E%2018,%20%22team2_id%22%20=%3E%203,%22team_ground%22%20=%3E%20%22Adeilade%22,%22matchdate%22%20=%3E%20%222016-04-01%22,%22matchtime%22%20=%3E%20%229:00%20AM%22),%5Cn%5Cn%20array%5Cn%20(%22team1_id%22%20=%3E%209,%22agegroup_id%22%20=%3E%2036,%22team2_id%22%20=%3E%204,%22team_ground%22%20=%3E%20%22Motera%20Stadium%22,%22matchdate%22%20=%3E%20%222016-04-13%22,%22matchtime%22%20=%3E%20%229:00%20AM%22%5Cn%20),%5Cn%5Cn%20array%5Cn%20(%22team1_id%22%20=%3E%204,%22agegroup_id%22%20=%3E%2036,%22team2_id%22%20=%3E%209,%22team_ground%22%20=%3E%20%22Motera%20Stadium%22,%22matchdate%22%20=%3E%20%222016-04-13%22,%22matchtime%22%20=%3E%20%225:00%20PM%22%5Cn%20),%5Cn%5Cn%20array%5Cn%20(%22team1_id%22%20=%3E%201,%22agegroup_id%22%20=%3E%2037,%22team2_id%22%20=%3E%208,%22team_ground%22%20=%3E%20%22Eden%20Garden%22,%22matchdate%22%20=%3E%20%222016-04-18%22,%22matchtime%22%20=%3E%20%227:00%20PM%22%5Cn%20),%5Cn%5Cn%20array%5Cn%20(%22team1_id%22%20=%3E%208,%22agegroup_id%22%20=%3E%2037,%22team2_id%22%20=%3E%201,%22team_ground%22%20=%3E%20%22Eden%20Garden%22,%22matchdate%22%20=%3E%20%222016-04-25%22,%22matchtime%22%20=%3E%20%228:00%20PM%22%5Cn%20),%5Cn%5Cn%20array%5Cn%20(%22team1_id%22%20=%3E%201,%22agegroup_id%22%20=%3E%2037,%22team2_id%22%20=%3E%208,%22team_ground%22%20=%3E%20%22Eden%20Garden%22,%22matchdate%22%20=%3E%20%2204/26/2016%22,%5Cn%20%22matchtime%22%20=%3E%20%228:00%20PM%22%5Cn%20),%5Cn%5Cn%20array%5Cn%20(%22agegroup_id%22%20=%3E%2018),%5Cn%5Cn%20array%5Cn%20(%22agegroup_id%22%20=%3E%2036),%5Cn%5Cn%20array%5Cn%20(%22agegroup_id%22%20=%3E%2037)%5Cn%5Cn);%5Cn$newArray%20=%20$array;%5Cnforeach%20($array%20as%20$key%20=%3E%20$value)%5Cn%20%7B%5Cn%20if(sizeOf($array[$key])%20%3C%202)%5Cn%20unset($newArray[$key]);%5Cn%20%7D%5Cnprint_r($newArray);%5Cn?%3E%5Cn)**

Comment: Thanks For Your reply but Uchiha's answer solved my problem. Thanks for your time and co operation.

Comment: @TaniPartner no problem